# VPython not working with Spyder 3.3.6 for Mac

Tags: python, terminal, vpython

I have downloaded VPython and am able to use in in my Terminal, but once I try and use it in Spyder it fails to work.

Running a simple test of:

`from vpython import *`

`sphere()`

I get a console read out that says:

`ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'vpython'`

This seems weird to me since I am able to get this working in a terminal window. I have tried substituting the "vpython" with "visual" and I get the same result.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

There were problems with using the vpython module with Spyder, but the latest version 7.5.2 has addressed those problems. If you are using Anaconda (recommended), here is how to update to the latest version of vpython:

To update to later versions of vpython use
     "conda update -c vpython vpython" or "pip install vpython --upgrade".